# /var/spool/cron: chdir: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, cron

I was using cron for a while on my Ubuntu workstation (16.04 LTS)

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And suddenly, out of the blue, I started getting `/var/spool/cron: chdir: Permission denied` from `crontab -l` (or `-e`) command. It seems that the problem might be with permissions (see e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/78159/what-could-cause-permission-denied-for-command-crontab-e) but all my attempts so far with resetting permissions on pertinent files (/var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard) did not resolve the issue

```
$ sudo namei -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard
f: /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard
drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxr-xr-x root    root    var
drwxr-xr-x root    root    spool
drwsrwxr-- root    root    cron
drwSrw-r-- root    crontab crontabs
-rwsrw-r-- ryszard crontab ryszard
$
```

Any ideas what could be a problem and how to fix it? And how this problem could arise in a first place?

Comment: This `-rwSrw-r--` looks strange, you set that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo namei -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard`

Comment: @George: Yes, I set it to -rwSrw-r-- . Following suggestions that crontabs files should not be executable I run "sudo chmod u-x /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard" which changed "s" to "S", but it does not make any difference i.e. I am getting
/var/spool/cron: chdir: Permission denied from crontab -l in both (s|S) cases/

Comment: @steeldriver: added "sudo namei -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard" per your suggestion.

Comment: @ryszard I would have expected the `cron` directory to be `drwxr-xr-x` (regular 755 octal directory perms) with `cron/crontabs` being `drwx-wx--T` (octal 1730 - "sticky" rather than setgid) and finally `cron/crontabs/ryszard` being `-rw-------` (octal 700).

Comment: Thank you @steeldrive - it helped!
Permissions are not exactly as listed above,
but crontab -e|-l execute properly now.
{{
$ sudo chmod  755 /var/spool/cron
$ sudo chmod 1730 /var/spool/cron/crontabs
$ sudo chmod  700 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard
$ sudo namei -l   /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard
f: /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ryszard
drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxr-xr-x root    root    var
drwxr-xr-x root    root    spool
drwsr-xr-x root    root    cron
drws-wx--T root    crontab crontabs
-rwx------ ryszard crontab ryszard
$ }}